# How to hide a text field dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am having 3 radio buttons r1, r2 and r3 and 4 text fields and text boxes..

If i am clicking r1, all the text field and text boxes should be hided. but if i am clicking r2 and r3 the text field and text box should be displayed..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use css property to achieve this. Use `display` or `visibility`.

Whenever r1 is active use as following:

```
document.getElementById("idOfTextField").style.display = "none";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("idOfTextField").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

And when r2 or r3 is active do as follow:

```
document.getElementById("idOfTextField").style.display = "block";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("idOfTextField").style.visibility = "visible";
```

You have to do this for all textboxes.

Note:- this is done using javaScript not jQuery.

Comment: @Shilpa: you should consider upvoting/accepting useful answers of questions you have asked.

Comment: Hi Harry,                                                                    Thanks for ur reply and help.

your code worked fine.

thanks again for valuable code...